# Windows form running as service encounters error 1053, but still works for a bit?

Tags: vb.net, service, windows-server-2016

I've got a Windows Form app that we just added as a service on our Windows Server 2016 server. When the app launches, it starts a 60 second timer. On launch, and again every 60 second tick, the app runs runs a job and reports back to the database.

When I go to start the service, the load bar speeds to 50% then creeps for a few seconds, then I get "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." Most of the cases I've seen about this involve an error occurring, but my app seems to be running fine until the service just gives up on running it. Any tips?

The code it gets through is pretty straightforward (unrelated bits trimmed out)

```
Private Sub Me_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call GoRun()
End Sub
Private Sub GoRun()

    If Not TimerToUpdate.Enabled Then
        TimerToUpdate.Interval = 60000
        TimerToUpdate.Enabled = True
        UpdateRunning = True
        Try
            Call RunUpdate() '''<< This is the job, which it gets through fine
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        UpdateRunning = False
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub UpdateTimer_Elapsed(source As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerToUpdate.Tick

    If Not UpdateRunning Then
        UpdateRunning = True

        Try
            Call RunUpdate()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        UpdateRunning = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're using a timer that causes your app not to respond to the ServiceStart function fast enough, and Windows is terminating it as a result. Why do you need a form in a service? Services don't show user interfaces (they don't run in the user desktop), and shouldn't have a UI at all. A  form is the wrong way to write a service app.

Comment: We've moved it to a service because it was running logged into an account on that server, but the account keeps logging out with inactivity. I've repeatedly deleted the registry key that causes the timeout, but it resets itself. It's a whole thing...

Comment: So the timer is the issue, it doesn't really seem like the UI is causing the problem, right? I agree that's not the ideal way to go, but how to get around the timer issue?

Comment: Don't activate the timer on startup. Respond promply to the ServiceStart call, so Windows doesn't shut you down because it thinks the service didn't start. Your best bet is to get rid of the form and timer entirely, and use a WinAPI event instead, and use a thread that is started in a proper service's main function after it replies to the startup call.

Comment: Another alternative is to stop trying to shoehorn an app that isn't a service into a service in the first place, and use a Windows scheduled task to run your app when it's needed. Assign it the user account that you want it to run under, and let Windows handle calling it on the proper schedule. Your app then starts, does what it needs to do, and exits. When it's due to run again, the Task Scheduler just starts it for you. You don't have to worry about the account being logged out for inactivity at all, and you don't create a new problem by asking a non-service app to work as a service.

Comment: I will definitely work on creating a proper service application for this and look into the WinAPI event. In the meantime, are you able to tell me how to make what I have respond to the ServiceStart call?

Comment: I've done that already. See two comments above your last one. *Don't activate the timer on startup. Respond properly to the ServiceStart call, so Windows doesn't shut you down because it thinks the service didn't start.* Don't enable the timer before your app fully starts, so that it immediately goes into the message loop and starts handling messages. Once it fully loads, you can start the timer.